# left sided limit of a monotonic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Definition:** Let $X,Y\subset\mathbb R$  and $f \colon X\to Y$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $X\cap(-\infty,x)$. If for all sequences $x_n\in X\cap(-\infty,x)$ it holds $f(x_n)\to y$, then $\lim_{x\to x^-}f(x)=y$.

My question: Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be monotonic with $a,b\in\mathbb R,a<b$. For which points of $[a,b]$ is the left sided limit defined?

I think it's defined for alle $x\in(a,b]$ since for $x=a$ we can't get any sequence.
This seems too easy for me. Is this right? And if not, for which is the left sided limit defined and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right!

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that $f$ is monotone increasing. If you take any $x\in(a,b]$, consider $A_x:=\{f(t)\mid t\in[a,x)\}$. Then $A_x$ is bounded above by $f(x)$, and so it has some least upper bound $L$.  See if you can prove that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow x^{-}}f(t)=L.
$$